# Milliseconds in POSIXct Class

Tags: r, posixct

How can I parse milliseconds correctly?

`as.POSIXct` function works as following in my environment.

```
> as.POSIXct("2014-02-24 11:30:00.001")
[1] "2014-02-24 11:30:00.000 JST"
> as.POSIXct("2014-02-24 11:30:00.0011")
[1] "2014-02-24 11:30:00.001 JST"
```

My R version is x86 v3.0.2 for Windows.

Answer (score 39):

Specify the input format, using `%OS` to represent the seconds with their fractional parts.

```
x <- c("2014-02-24 11:30:00.123", "2014-02-24 11:30:00.456")
y <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

When you come to display the value, append a number between 0 and 6 to the format string to tell R how many decimal places of seconds to display.

```
format(y, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
## [1] "2014-02-24 11:30:00.122999" "2014-02-24 11:30:00.456000"
```

(Note that you get rounding errors, and R's datetime formatting always rounds downwards, so if you show less decimal places it sometimes looks like you've lost a millisecond.)

Datetime formats are documented on the `?strptime` help page. The relevant paragraph is:

> ```
>  Specific to R is '%OSn', which for output gives the seconds
>  truncated to '0 <= n <= 6' decimal places (and if '%OS' is not
>  followed by a digit, it uses the setting of
>  'getOption("digits.secs")', or if that is unset, 'n = 3').
>  Further, for 'strptime' '%OS' will input seconds including
>  fractional seconds.  Note that '%S' ignores (and not rounds)
>  fractional parts on output.
> ```

Comment: The format arg when defining `y` is not necessary