# Creating a POSIXct date in R from date and time parts

Tags: r

How do I create a POSIXct date from the date and time  parts below

```
 date<-as.Date("2014-01-01")
 hour<-5
 minute<-15
 second<-59
 millisecond<-695

 date
 hour
  minute
 second
 millisecond
```

output should be a POSIXct object

2014-01-01 05:15:59.695

Comment: Start by pasting the elements together using `paste()` and then refer to [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037657/milliseconds-in-posixct-class)

Comment: Also see `?ISOdatetime`

Answer (score 5):

The following should do it:
First set options to be able to display milliseconds

```
options(digits.secs=3)
```

Next paste the date elements to form a date string

```
date_string <- paste(date, paste(paste(hour,minute,second,sep=":"),millisecond,sep="."),sep = " ")
```

Then convert to a POSIXct object

```
as.POSIXct(date_string,tz="",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```