# Converting to Date Time Using as.POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a column "DateTime". 
Example value: 2016-12-05-16.25.54.875000

When I import this, R reads it as a Factor.

Now, when I sort the dataset by decreasing "DateTime", the maximum DateTime is 23 June 2017. When I use DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime), it changes to 22 June 2017. How is this happening?

P.S. I am running this R script in Power BI.

Comment: did you try specifying format as in `as.POSIXct(datatime, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S")`

Comment: I see you have milliseconds too. See this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037657/milliseconds-in-posixct-class

Answer (score 0):

So some comments first. When you read strings in R, unless you specify otherwise they are imported as factors. You can use the Option

Trying what @Disco Superfly has suggested works if you define the data as a string in R

```
> a <- "2016-12-05-16.25.54.875000"
> as.POSIXct(a, format="%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S") 
[1] "2016-12-05 16:25:54 CET"
> as.POSIXct(a)
[1] "2016-12-05 CET"
```

Is not clear what you are saying about the fact that the data is being changed. Can you give a reproducible example?

To summarize, if your Dates are strings that what other have already suggested works perfectly. I suppose you are trying to do more than what you are explaining and therefore I don't understand what you are saying exactly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
Si when I do as.POSIXct in R, it converts without any problem. This issue arises when I do the same using the R scripting option in Power BI.

Comment: Check this link https://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2016/08/27/working-with-date-fields-in-r-and-power-bi/#ampshare=https://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2016/08/27/working-with-date-fields-in-r-and-power-bi/ it maybe helpful. The same happens with SAS, since it uses a different origin to calculate Dates.