# Add milliseconds column to datetime

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

The dataframe looks like

```
datetime            msec    value 

2022-07-19 17:30:00 8       5   
2022-07-19 17:30:00 58      9   
2022-07-19 17:30:00 108     3
```

I want to add the milliseconds to the datetime like this

```
datetime               value  
2022-07-19 17:30:00.008   5    
2022-07-19 17:30:00.058   9   
2022-07-19 17:30:00.108   3
```

I tried

```
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(dfdatetime, df$msec), format="%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse it the correct format to make it work. This can be done in several ways.

**Adding the milliseconds** (Thanks to @Ritchie Sacramento for this point):

```r
new_datetime <- df$datetime + df$msec/1000
```

**Or using `lubridate`**:

```r
new_datetime <- df$datetime + lubridate::milliseconds(df$msec)
```

**Paste it like your own approach:**

Beware though:

- With a `.` between seconds and milliseconds, no spaces (thus `paste0`).
- Date format with `-` not `/`
- To pad the milliseconds with zeros (Thanks to @Ritchie Sacramento for this point)

```r
df$new_datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(df$datetime, ".", sprintf("%03d", df$msec)), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

**Output:** (there will be rounding/representation errors) *

```
options(digits.secs=3)

df

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  datetime                 msec value new_datetime           
  <dttm>                  <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                 
1 2022-07-19 17:30:00.000     8     5 2022-07-19 17:30:00.007
2 2022-07-19 17:30:00.000    58     9 2022-07-19 17:30:00.058
3 2022-07-19 17:30:00.000   108     3 2022-07-19 17:30:00.108
```

**Alternatively**: Format it to show the milliseconds with 3 digits.

```r
format(df$new_datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

[1] "2022-07-19 17:30:00.007" "2022-07-19 17:30:00.058" "2022-07-19 17:30:00.108"
```

**Data:**

```
library(readr)

df <- read_delim("datetime,msec,value
2022-07-19 17:30:00,8,5
2022-07-19 17:30:00,58,9
2022-07-19 17:30:00,108,3")
```

(*) See [Milliseconds in POSIXct Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037657/milliseconds-in-posixct-class)

**Update:** Fix the parsing errors. Sorry for not being aware!

Comment: A nice summary of options, as an addition when it is for formatting only `sprintf("%s.%03d", df$datetime, df$msec)` would do and has no rounding errors and otherwise `as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s.%03d", df$datetime, df$msec))` can be used as alternative approach.